# Android Trusted Web App: does not filter in input type=file while it does in the web app

Tags: android, trusted-web-activity

I have a webapp that when opened in a browser, the user can select a file (using the `<input type="file" accept="image/*">`. As expected this lists the image type of files from the mobile. On selection the app processes it.

When I convert the same to a Trusted Web App (TWA) pointing to the same URL, I find the the button shows all files from the directories. The accept filter does not seem to apply. In any case, if I chose the correct file type, the app does process.

Is something to be set on the manifest side to get this working? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the Trusted Web Activity the application should behave in exactly the same way it does in a regular browser tab, so this seems to be a browser bug to me.

If the browser in question is Chrome, please file a bug at https://crbug.com/.

Comment: okay. will re-check before filing. Thanks @andreban